# Laravel 5.3, Custom Css/Js not working

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel and working on a product. The issue I am facing is with loading JS and CSS files.

I have placed all the CSS and JS files inside assets folder and accessing them following way :

**CSS :**

```
 <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-select.css')}}">
<!--    Font Awesome CSS   -->
<link href="{{asset('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="{{asset('css/ionicons.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Owl carousel -->
<link href="{{asset('css/owl.carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('css/owl.theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/owl.transitions.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--    Custome CSS   -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/nanoscroller.css')}}" type='text/css'>
<link href="{{asset('css/jquery.bxslider.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/menu.css')}}">
<link href="{{asset('css/all.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and

**JS :**

```
<!-- JS   -->
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap-select.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery.nanoscroller.js')}}">    </script>
<script defer src="{{asset('js/bx.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/menu.js')}}"></script> 
<script src="{{asset('js/owl.carousel.js')}}" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
```

This is exact the same way as it was working fine with the default js & css files come with fresh laravel installation like this :

**Default CSS & JS (working) :**

```
  <link href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

What I am missing here ? Do I have to use the gulp and compile all of js and css into default app.css and app.js files ?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend using Gulp to concatenate these files.  If a file only needs to be on one page, it is ok to load separately. But if you need files on all pages, combine them into one file and minify it.  This will save you loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This points to the `public` dir not to the `assets` dir, move your files to `public/css` and `public/js`, use `assets` dir when your are using `gulp`.

If you would like to combine some plain CSS stylesheets into a single file, you may use the `styles` method. Paths passed to this method are relative to the `resources/assets/css` directory and the resulting CSS will be placed in `public/css/all.css` :

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        'normalize.css',
        'main.css'
    ]);
});
```

for `js` use `mix.scripts`

Answer (score 1):

Add /

```
    <link href="{{asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/bootstrap-select.css')}}">
<!--    Font Awesome CSS   -->
<link href="{{asset('/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="{{asset('/css/ionicons.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Owl carousel -->
<link href="{{asset('/css/owl.carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('/css/owl.theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('/css/owl.transitions.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--    Custome CSS   -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/nanoscroller.css')}}" type='text/css'>
<link href="{{asset('/css/jquery.bxslider.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/menu.css')}}">
<link href="{{asset('/css/all.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And JS

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/bootstrap-select.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/js/jquery.nanoscroller.js')}}">    </script>
<script defer src="{{asset('/js/bx.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/menu.js')}}"></script> 
<script src="{{asset('/js/owl.carousel.js')}}" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried this but no luck. It is not loading css and js.